# Create 40 - 60% cache misses in the different levels of cache

Tags: x86-64, cpu-cache

I am trying to create lots of cache misses in L1 and L2 cache, if possible to thrash the cache. The example below is a section of the code I am working on. In this code, c_size is the size of L1, L2 and L3 cache. On my system, I have L1, L2, L3 to be 32Kb,256Kb, and 2048kb respectively. The cache line is 64 bytes. My goal is to create cache misses as I read or/and write to memory. I have tried using different array sizes but I get few cache misses(less than expected). The aim would be 50%. I am not sure what I am not doing well. Please, can someone explain how to achieve this?

```
 // allocate memory at an aligned address
  int PAGE_SIZE = getpagesize();
  int n_pages = c_size / PAGE_SIZE;
  if (c_size % PAGE_SIZE != 0) n_pages++;
  size_t alloc_size = n_pages * PAGE_SIZE;
  void *x = mmap ((void *)mmap_addr, alloc_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
             MAP_FIXED|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, (off_t)0);
  if (x == MAP_FAILED || x != mmap_addr) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory at %p: %s\n", mmap_addr, 
  strerror(errno));
  exit (1);

  }


  char *addr;
  int rand_t,rval;
  uint64_t urand;
  int i,j;
  unsigned int A[32768];
  uint64_t temp = 0xff000000ul << 24;

  if (access_type == Write){
  for(i = 0; i < 64; i++){
  rand_t = rand();
  A[i]=rand_t & temp;
  rval = rand_t & temp; // random byte 
  addr = (char *) (mmap_addr+(rand_t % c_size));
 //*addr = rval;
*addr = A[i];

 //asm("rdrand %r14");
  //printf("%p:\t%x\tmem:%hhx\n", addr, rval, *addr);
}
```

Comment: L1d and L2 are set-associative on Intel, so if you use a large power of 2 stride you can get lots of conflict misses without a huge working set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not get high cache misses on L1 and L2 with this. However, the L3 cache miss rate is very high.